# What replaces refFunctions plugin's intersecting_geom_count function?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, overlapping-features, count, function

I have been away for quite a while and it is probably a couple of years since I used the atlas features. I upgraded to QGIS 3.24 and I have just tried to generate an atlas from a saved layout. That failed and I eventually realized that the problem was in the filter expression, furthermore the "refFunctions" plugin was not installed and was not in the list of available plugins (the filter contained a function supplied by the plugin).

I searched and found that the plugin's functionality was now included in the core but failed to find any hint of what the new functions were called.

For the record my current filter is:

```
intersecting_geom_count('Nest Boxes') > 0
```

where `'Nest Boxes'` is the name of a layer.

Where in the docs is the new function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) these are now the [overlay functions](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects), in that case:

```
array_length(overlay_intersects('Nest Boxes', $id))
```

The overlay functions return an array of the requested values, in this example of the feature `"id"`s. To get the count of intersecting features you need to measure the length of the array by using [`array_length()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-length).

See the docs for a full list of functions in 3.22 (current LTR):
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html