# intersecting_geom_sum function is no longer available in QGIS 3.22.12

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, field-calculator, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon

When I was using QGIS 2.18.16 I could calculate the average values of points intersecting the grid with:

```
intersecting_geom_sum('Layer1', 'Value')/"Numpoints"
```

I had the plugin ["refFunctions"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) installed, which is outdated as of QGIS 3.14.

The expression above no longer functions under QGIS 3.22.12 in the Field Calculation.

What plugin should I install and/or which expression can I use to calculate my average values in the same way as I did when I was using QGIS 2.18.16?

Answer (score 2):

As it says on the ["refFunctions"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin's page:

> This plugin is deprecated!
>
> The plugin is outdated as of QGIS 3.14 due to the introduction of the
> new functions for geometry overlay expressions

Therefore, I will encourage you to pay attention to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439636/99589) from @MrXsquared:

> These are now the [overlay functions](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core).

So, your solution can be the following:

```
array_sum(overlay_contains('points', "Value")) #730
```

Here the [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) and [`array_sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-sum) functons were deployed.

However, if one still feels in love with the `intersecting_geom_sum()` function, it is possible to recreate it by means of [the original source code](https://github.com/enricofer/refFunctions/blob/master/reffunctions.py#L1429) and the [Function Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor).

Create a custom function i.e. `intersecting_geom_sum` and paste the following code into the editor:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=2, group='Custom', referenced_columns=[], register=True, usesgeometry=True)
def intersecting_geom_sum(values, feature, parent):
    """
        Sums the geometries' attributes of the target layer intersected by the source feature
        
        <h4>Syntax</h4>
        <p>intersecting_geom_sum(<i>'target_layer_name','Field_name_to_sum'</i>)</p>
        <h4>Arguments</h4>
        <p><i>  target_layer_name</i> : name of the target layer, for exemple 'COUNTRIES'.<br>
        <i> Field_name_to_sum</i> : name of the field to sum, for exemple 'POPULATION' <br></p>
        <h4>Example</h4>
        <p><!-- Show example of function.-->
             intersecting_geom_sum('COUNTRIES','POPULATION') &rarr; 2165</p>
        
    """ 
    targetLayerName = values[0]
    targetFieldName = values[1]
    
    if feature.geometry() is not None:
        layerSet = {layer.name():layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()}

        count = 0.0
        
        request = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest()
        request.setFilterRect(feature.geometry().boundingBox())

        for feat in layerSet[targetLayerName].layer().getFeatures(request):
                if feat.geometry().intersects(feature.geometry()):
                    try:
                        count += float(feat[targetFieldName])
                    except:
                        #case feat[targetFieldName] is null or string....
                        pass
        return count
```

[image: editor]

Then click the <kbd>Save and Load Functions</kbd>, switch to the Expression tab, and call:

```
intersecting_geom_sum('points', 'Value') #730
```

[image: expression]

Both examples were applied to the following test data:

[image: test]

Answer (score 1):

You could use this expression:

```
with_variable ('point',
    aggregate (
        layer: = 'point',
    aggregate: = 'array_agg',
   expression: = "value",
       filter: = intersects ($geometry, geometry(@parent))),
array_sum (@point)
/
array_length (@point))
```

[image]